# Apache Spark SQL can not SELECT Cassandra timestamp columns

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I created Docker containers in which I installed Apache Spark 3.1.2 (Hadoop 3.2) that host a ThriftServer which is configured to access Cassandra via the [spark-cassandra-connector(3.1.0)](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector). Each of these services is running in it's own container. So I got 5 containers up (1x spark master, 2x spark worker, 1x spark thriftserver, 1x cassandra) which are configured to live in the same network via docker-compose.
I use the beeline client from Apache Hive(1.2.1) to query the database. Everything works fine, except for querying a field in Cassandra with the type `timestamp`.

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 9 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 9.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 53) (192.168.80.5 executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.time.Instant
```

I checked the Spark/spark-cassandra-connector documentations but didn't find much except for a [configuration property called spark.sql.datetime.java8API.enabled](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-sql-configuration) which

```
If the configuration property is set to true, java.time.Instant and java.time.LocalDate classes of Java 8 API are used as external types for Catalyst's TimestampType and DateType. If it is set to false, java.sql.Timestamp and java.sql.Date are used for the same purpose.
```

I think this property could maybe help in my case. Despite saying in the docs that the default value is false, the value is always `true` in my case. I don't set it anywhere and I've tried overwriting it with `false` in the `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf` file and via the `--conf` commandline parameters when starting up ThriftServer (and master/worker instances), but the environment tab (at `localhost:4040`) always shows it as `true`.

Is there a way to make Spark convert the timestamps in a way that doesn't lead to an exception? It would be important to do that in SQL since I want to connect software for data visualization later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-35679) which mentions that there was a bug converting times which is not fixed in 3.1.2 (3.1.3 is not released yet), but in 3.0.3.
I downgraded Apache Spark(3.0.3) and spark-cassandra-connector(3.0.1) which seems to solve the problem for now.